# Dynamically change Bundle Loader of Unit Test

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process

I have an Xcode project with multiple targets, but I want the same Unit Test to run across all of them.

I have created the Unit Test and attached it to each target in my project (using the Edit Scheme>Test menu). Xcode still uses the "Bundle Loader" project setting to determine which app to run when performing a Test though.

So I created an .xcconfig file which the Unit Test uses. This is what it looks like:

```
SO_BUILDING_PRODUCT_NAME = None
BUNDLE_LOADER = $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$(SO_BUILDING_PRODUCT_NAME).app/$SO_BUILDING_PRODUCT_NAME
```

As you can see, it's pretty straightforward. I then wrote a bash script which will change "None" to the actual name of the Xcode target that is being built. I then added this script to each target's Pre-Actions Build phase.

I can see as soon as I tell Xcode to Test, the .xcconfig file updates instantly and I can even see Xcode's UI for the Unit Test update automatically. Unfortunately though each time I change my target, I have to build twice for the change to take effect. It seems like I'm making my change too late for Xcode to notice or care.

Does anyone have some suggestions about how to force Xcode to take notice of the change I make at the start of the Build process?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen (although I haven't explored this since Xcode 5 was released), as soon as you hit Build, it's impossible to change any build settings via .xcconfig files, Xcode seems to take a snapshot before you get the chance to run any scripts or anything like that.

Unless those limitations of dynamic .xcconfig configuration have changed, you will need to try a different approach. I'm not familiar with BUNDLE_LOADER, but if you can change that *variable* via a script, rather than changing the .xcconfig file itself, you may have more luck.